# awk - Adding a column with value found in next line, if patter is matched

Tags: awk, conditional-statements, pattern-matching

I am trying to transform this file

```
keyn,assert,code
"11","1","25"
"11","1","21"
"11","1","40"
"12","0","35"
"12","0","10"
```

to this one:

```
keyn,assert,code,code
"11","1","25","21"
"11","1","40","0"
"12","0","35","0"
"12","0","10","0"
```

i.e. for the first instance of `keyn`, if `assert == "1"`, print `$3` of the next register at the end of the line and delete that line, and if `assert == "0"`, print just `"0"` at the end of the line.

Until now, I tried this, without success:

```
awk  'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","} {num[NR] = $3; if ($2=="1") {print $0, num[i+1]} else {print $0,"0" }}' file
```

Comment: why is it `"11","1","40","0"` instead of `"11","1","40","35"` ?

Comment: @Fravadona, because that is a different `keyn` instance. Each `keyn` is a different "transaction", so they don't relate between them.

Comment: @dsv87: In the first step I recommend you to write pseudo code. So far your description is not conclusive.

Comment: none of your 2nd fields contain the 1-character string `1` .... they all contain 3-character strings `"0"` or `"1"` ... so the current 1-character test (`$2=="1"`) will never return 'true' ... perhaps something like `$2=="\"1\""` is what you want? alternative would be to strip the double quotes from the values (eg, `gsub()` or splitting lines based on field patterns - `FPAT`)

Comment: re: `num[i+1]` ... where does the variable `i` get set? as currently coded `i` is never set so any reference to `i` will default to `0` (ie, `num[i+1]` will always be evaluated as `num[1]`)

Comment: *`because is a different keyn instance`* seems to indicate that you want to compare `keyn` values (ie, 1st field) between lines, but nowhere do you reference let alone compare `$1`; if you want to compare `keyn` values then consider updating the question with more details on how the `keyn` field is to be used and/or compared

Comment: please update the question to explain what you mean by *`without success`*; do you get an error? no output? wrong output? something else?

Comment: [edit] your question to show what the last line of output should look like if the last line of input was `"13","1","10"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR == 1 {
    print $0, "code"
    next
}
$1 != prev {
    prev = $1
    if ( $2 == "\"" 1 "\"" ) {
        saved = $0
        next
    }
}
{
    print ( saved == "" ? $0 OFS "\"0\"" : saved OFS $3 )
    saved = ""
}
END {
    if ( saved != "" ) {
        print saved OFS "\"0\""
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
keyn,assert,code,code
"11","1","25","21"
"11","1","40","0"
"12","0","35","0"
"12","0","10","0"
```

I'm assuming above that if your last row of input starts with a new `keyn` value you want that line printed with a `"0"` at the end, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
keyn,assert,code
"11","1","25"
"11","1","21"
"11","1","40"
"12","0","35"
"12","0","10"
"13","1","10"
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
keyn,assert,code,code
"11","1","25","21"
"11","1","40","0"
"12","0","35","0"
"12","0","10","0"
"13","1","10","0"
```

but it's obviously an easy tweak to do just about anything else in that case if that's not what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a couple of variables to carry values over to the next record:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","; zero = "\"0\""}
    NR == 1 {print $0, "code"; next}
    prev != "" {
        print prev, $1 == key ? $3 : zero
        prev = ""
        if ($1 == key) next
    }
    {key = $1}
    $2 ~ /1/ {prev = $0; next}
    {print $0, zero}
' file
```

This works on the sample data you show. No guarantees.